# Android: Jank on initial scroll with RecyclerView in debug

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have a simple test application which has a social media-like layout:
[image]

It consists of an outer recycler view for posts and nested RV for comments (with indentation on the screenshot).

**The issue:**
Mostly in debug mode, there's a considerable jank **only when the initial scroll happens** (probably some initialization stuff of RVs). Further scrolling is smooth both in debug and release. In release, it happens mostly after usage of some intensive apps, e.g. watching videos on Facebook app. And the jank is less noticeable if it happens in release.
[Systrace when the initial scroll happens](https://easyupload.io/s7a3qu)

**Setup details**

Phone - Nexus 5X with Android 8.1,
compileSdkVersion - 28,
minSdkVersion - 16,
targetSdkVersion - 28

**The relevant pieces of code are as follows:**

[The outer RV's adapter](https://pastebin.com/TUCVME42) - here I'm using the posts data with their comments and also the nested RV pool so that nested RVs can take advantage of that. The view holder just stores some references to different controls in the view. **onCreateViewHolder** is the place where I tried some optimizations, including pre-creating 10 view holders (the current code). I've set **setHasFixedSize** to true, but that didn't help. The layout manager for the RV is **LinearLayoutManager** without any customization.

```
if (viewHolders.size == 0) {
        //Log.w("msg", "creating all view holders")
        for (i in 1..10) {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.wallpost_view, parent, false) as LinearLayout
            val viewHolder = MyViewHolder(v, context, nestedViewsPool)
            viewHolders.push(viewHolder)
        }
    }
```

[The inner RV's adapter](https://pastebin.com/EpkTR6kx) - nothing special here as it currently doesn't contain any custom events.

[Outer RV item's view](https://pastebin.com/ZvAdaeCN) - **Yes, it uses nested layouts**, but I didn't see any performance difference when coverting it to ConstraintLayout, [CL version here](https://pastebin.com/8Xc15biT).

[Inner RV item's view](https://pastebin.com/s1jE8Kaz) - Nothing special here, looks similar to the outer item's view, but without buttons and links. [CL version here](https://pastebin.com/DNVTKEpq)

What can cause the jank? It's been there (in debug) since I initialy tested even with simplified views and code.

Comment: i am also facing this problem, I have the same device and have simple list item xml, not complex like you, but still have jank on initial scrolls.

Comment: the point you mentioned about intensive device usage is correct, I have noticed it too but you don't have to worry about that, after intense usage this jank behavior is normal. I mean games too lag when device heats up

Comment: You're probably right that first scroll might be slower by design, but I didn't see anything about it on the web. The only thing I've come with so far, is the stuff in my answer.

Comment: `LinearLayout` is too slow. Never use them. Use `RelativeLayout` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer since it does what I require - it reduces the time the first scroll takes.

I moved pre-creation of the two types of view holders in the calling activity:

```
for (i in 1..30) {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.wallpost_view, parent, false) as LinearLayout
    val viewHolder = MyViewHolder(v, context, nestedViewsPool)
    viewHolders.push(viewHolder)
}

for (i in 1..20) {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.comment_view, null) as LinearLayout
    val viewHolder = WallpostsListAdapter.CommentsViewHolder(v)
    adapter.commentViewHolders.push(viewHolder)
}
```

This made the first scroll arround 2 times faster in most of the tests I conducted. **And this action lead to the biggest gain in the optimization process.**

I also adopted part of **@Fabio**'s suggestions:

**1.** As I stated in the comments, I measure that stuff in debug mode to
be able to better see the optimization results. In release, of
course, the numbers in milliseconds will be much smaller (actually
arround 10 times smaller from what I saw in the systrace in
release).

**2.** This was the point that made the biggest difference, not huge
difference but still it could be spotted in systrace. Check pastebins in the end of the answer for more info.

**3.** Indeed, Google recommends using `ContraintLayout` instead of nested
layouts, but in my case this didn't make any difference. **Actually
nested linear layouts seemed to show slightly better resutls.** My
guess is that the views are not complex enough to see the gain with
CL. I couldn't test the final optimized code with nested linear
layouts, because I now use single multi-type view RV and they
weren't working correctly with it, couldn't find the reason, but
probably the gain wouldn't have been that significant.

**4.** Good point, but it didn't make any signifcant difference in my case, at least.

**5.** Obsolete as there is now only a single RV without nesting.

**Relevant code**

- [RV's adapter](https://pastebin.com/Kq6QnnyX) - now a multi-type view adapter, managing both
  posts and comments. The biggest change was that I needed to write
  mapping code between RV position and array index. Now on init I need
  to do that mapping. In comment's VH binding, I first need to get
  their parent post's RV position, from there the index in the array
  and finally from their difference to get the comment's index within
  post's comments array.
- [Post's view with ConstraintLayout](https://pastebin.com/pXvZdFWk)
- [Comment's view with CL](https://pastebin.com/97tcyBgN)

**Systraces**

- Views with CL, all view holders pre-created, single RV - [here](https://gofile.io/d/xJzrmC)
- Views with CL, only post's VH pre-created, single RV - [here](https://gofile.io/d/M8hZMs)

Comment: If this is not your answer, you should include it in your question instead.

Comment: @MDP Users are encouraged to ask and answer their own questions. I think he's not accepting as an official answer because he's still looking for alternative.

Comment: Very interesting point on (3). I'll make my own benchmarks next time I have to decide which way to go instead of blindingly using CL

Comment: Yeah, I'm now learning Android so no expert by any means, but just before I used ````ConstraintLayout```` for the first time, I checked this: https://android.jlelse.eu/constraint-layout-performance-870e5f238100 I haven't looked into the code used for these tests, only at the numbers. But we can see there's a bit of a slowdown in my example, too. I'll probably dig into it deeper in the future.

Answer (score 5):

A few things to take care of

1- do not measure performance in debug mode

I can't emphasize this enough. Run without debugger attached and you will see drastic performance improvements.

2- flatten your design

Instead of having RV where each item has a RV, use a single RecyclerView with different cells. So 1st cell would be "content of wallpost", 2nd would be "wallpost answer 1", 3rd "wallpost answer 2" etc.

I've been struggling hard to make one of my screens perform better where we have horizontal RV (viewPager 2 to be specific) with nested vertical RV, and I chased many dead ends, and ended up having to pull some tricks like disabling preload of previous/next page until the current page has been loaded. But it does NOT struggle after initial load.

3- Having `<include` in layouts is not likely to make it slower.

But having nested hierarchies does, like:

```
<LinearLayout> 
  <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
```

Consider rewriting everything as a single ConstraintLayout. Your UI is not that complicated. Delete a few things, measure it, and if it gets significantly better make the conversion. I'd start with the inner layout since there's potentially more of them in a single screen?

and last

4- be careful with date conversions

I noticed that there are some methods in ThreeTenAbp that consume an unreasonable amount of time. Try skipping all those methods replacing it with dummy strings, and check if it makes any difference. IF it does, you have a couple of options, but these are my 2 initial suspects

- initialize date formatters only once, and use them in background thread
- check your date parsers are running in a background thread

I wouldn't be surprised if Java 8 DateTime has the same issues.

================

After writing all of the above I took a look at your systrace. From looking quickly the culprit seems to be the nested linear layouts. I can see around 1.880 ms that there's a very long inflate taking 30ms, that's a big red flag. It has 3 linear layouts inside, which would tend to point in the general direction of either the inner or outer layout. So I'd give it a try at (3) first and if not enough I'd try (2).

==============
Edit: adding (5)

5- sharing a RecycledViewPool for inner recyclerview

Create a single object of type RecycledViewPool and assign it to all your inner recyclerviews.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Regarding your points:
**1** - The reason I check it with debug is because it's more obvious if I make a performance improvement. Frames in release are fast and sometimes it's difficult if it really has made a difference. Of course, in release as pure numbers the gain in milliseconds would be way less than in debug.
**2** - I'll think about it but not sure exactly how I'll do it. The data I have is a bit hierarchical. That is in the screenshot 1 post has 2 answers. I'll have to probably flatten the data

Comment: **3** - One of the first things I tried. Measurements showed that converting it to ContraintLayout made it a little bit slower, so I don't think anything can be done here (probably I doesn't matter much how I use the constraints, e.g. if I use ```app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf``` or ```app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf```, but you can confirm also). I can show the CL equivalent I've made if necessary.
**4** - Do you refer to the code in The inner RV's adapter and the time difference? How can that be improved?

Comment: 1- totally makes sense, but there's no guarantees everything gets slowed by the same amount, so you may end up chasing something that's not the slowest. 3- I never went through that myself but that's what google devs keep repeating every year. Can you show your converted layout for BOTH inner and outer RV? 4- lately I treat any method from DateTime or ThreeTen as a potential time hog - so it would apply for both inner and outer. However I couldn't find them in systrace.

Comment: I updated my question with CL version of the outer view. Tested once again, still slightly slower (probably not that noticeable in release, but in debug it's more obvious). For now I haven't converted the inner view to CL as well. Will write back when I've done so and measured results. Thanks!

Comment: For note **5** - I'm already using that optimization for the inner views ;)

Comment: Added also the CL version of the inner view. Not much difference, I guess. Note that I still need ```LinearLayout``` there so that the gray background doesn't cover the avatar to the left.

Comment: You can create an extra view, and set  it as `startToEndOf=image` `endToEndOf=parent`

Comment: I've edited my answer with the final code. Thank you very much for your effort!