# android-force recyclerview to create needed views at beginning

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using 3 different view types in a recyclerview. since one of them contains a list of views, it is kind of *heavy* and needs more time to be created. so whenever the recyclerview arrives at the beginning of these views and needs to create them (in addition to binding), I experience jank.

in order to solve the issue, **I need the recyclerview to create as many views as it needs at the initialization level and then when the user scrolls just binds the data to already-created views.** how can I force recyclerview to create all needed views in begining?

I already tried to create a `RecycledViewPool` which contains the required view holders, but the pool does not accept the added viewHolders for some reason:

```
RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool recycledViewPool = recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool();
recycledViewPool.putRecycledView(recyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(recyclerView, Model.TYPE_1));
collectionsRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(recycledViewPool);
```

Comment: Please clarify where / when you tried to create the RecycledViewPool

Answer (score 2):

**You should use `recyclerViewAdapter.createViewHolder` instead of `recyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder`** because (documentation):

> This method calls onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int) to create a new RecyclerView.ViewHolder *and initializes some private fields to be used by RecyclerView.*

**Also make sure to call `recyclerViewAdapter.setMaxRecycledViews(Model.TYPE_1, MAX)` with a sufficiently large `MAX` value.**

This works great for me even though [this interesting article](https://medium.com/android-news/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-404ba3453714) in general warns against using `putRecycledView()` manually:

> Using putRecycledView() manually, e.g. in order to prepare some ViewHolders beforehand, is a bad idea, though. You should create ViewHolder only in onCreateViewHolder() method of your Adapter, otherwise the ViewHolders can appear in states that RecyclerView doesn’t expect.
>
> E.g. the correct view type is set in createViewHolder() method right after the Adapter call, and the field is package local, so you can’t set it yourself.

However I see no problem since *we are* calling `createViewHolder()`.

Alternatively you could simply use your own pool:

```
val pool = LinkedList<H>()
var ini = true

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder { 
    if (ini) 
        for (i in 0 until 10)
            pool.push(createYourViewHolder())
    ini = false

    // if it needs more than expected
    if (pool.size == 0) pool.push(createYourViewHolder())

    return pool.pop()
}
```

That way, when the recyclerview is created, becomes visible and requests the first view (and no scrolling should be happening), reserve views are created, and following calls to `onCreateViewHolder` will take virtually no time, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820892/android-jank-on-initial-scroll-with-recyclerview-in-debug).

This is what I used previously and also works.